# XSL execute a section inside a for..each only once

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to execute a section in XSL inside `for-each` loop only once. I do not know the `position` in loop where the node will be empty.

```
<xsl:for-each select="SomeNode">        
    <xsl:if test="CONDITION 1">
        <!-- SHOW Node Value -->
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="(current() = '')"> <!-- If node is empty -->
        <!-- SHOW default value, but only once -->
        Node Value Empty
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

For ex:,

```
<Nodes>
   <SomeNode>Node Value 1</SomeNode>
   <SomeNode></SomeNode>
   <SomeNode></SomeNode>
   <SomeNode>Node Value 2</SomeNode>       
   <SomeNode></SomeNode>
   <SomeNode></SomeNode>
   <SomeNode></SomeNode>
   <SomeNode>Node Value 3</SomeNode>       
   ...
</Nodes>
```

In the above XML, I am expecting an output like below,

```
Node Value 1
Node Value Empty
Node Value 2
Node Value 3
.. (an so on only if SomeNode is not empty)
```

How can I check and execute the empty node condition only once inside a for-each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
<xsl:template match="/Nodes">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SomeNode[normalize-space()] | SomeNode[not(normalize-space())][1]"/>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SomeNode[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SomeNode[not(normalize-space())]">
    <xsl:text>Node Value Empty</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes you need the first empty node to appear at its original position - otherwise it could be simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="/Nodes">
    <xsl:for-each select="SomeNode[normalize-space()]"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    <xsl:if test="SomeNode[not(normalize-space())]">
        <xsl:text>Node Value Empty</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It worked and I am clueless. Sorry, I am new to XSL and learning my way while making few changes for my project. `SomeNode[not(normalize-space())][1]` - does this mean select only one instance of empty node?

**Also could you post the simpler solution you had mentioned? Position may not matter.**

Comment: `SomeNode[not(normalize-space())][1]` means the first empty instance of `Somenode` (by using `normalize-space()` I have extended the definition of "empty" to include nodes with whitespace-only text). -- I have added the simpler solution to my answer.

Comment: Very nice logic, plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't do what you are asking with a for-each. Think of a for-each as processing all the items in the selection *in parallel* rather than *in sequence*. The processing of one item cannot depend in any way on what other items are present in the selection (except for the use of `position()` and `last()`).

If you want to process a sequence sequentially (one item at a time) then in general in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 you need recursion. In 3.0 you can use xsl:iterate.

But where the selected nodes are siblings, as in this case, there is also the option when processing a particular node to examine its surroundings in the tree. It's not possible when processing a node within xsl:for-each to ask "is this is the first selected node with condition C", but it is possible to ask "does this node have any preceding siblings with condition C".